# How to show fieldnames and severity in SNMP CA Spectrum?

Tags: snmp, mib, snmp-trap

Conditions:
CA Console spectrum server receives SNMP traps (events), MIB definition file loaded to CA system.

Problem:
In events list I don't see color severity and I see only OIDs, but not fields names described by MIB file.

Does anyone have any suggestions about that?

Comment: Can you share you MIB definition file?

Comment: Might I do this in private ?

Comment: May be you can use mock info to show similar configuration

Comment: https://codepaste.net/v3d6dj

Comment: If it might be some valueble, MIB file susccesefully compiled by CA Spectrum MIB tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is resolved. Problem was not in MIB file, but in SNMP trap sender: it was sent trap ID incorrect and of course CA spectrim don't recognize event.
I Used library Lextm.SharpSnmpLib. Function Messenger.SendTrapV2 has parameter called "enterprise". But you must don't provide enterpriseOID to this parameter, you need to provide TRAP ID (!!!). It's non sense, but it working!